# Laravel Composer stopped work

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

My composer stopped working I have no idea why. I tried to undo the changes at my application and still not working. So I tried to reinstall laravel, but now I can not use composer install. I get this message:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: 
failed to open stream: Connection timed out
```

If I run composer diagnose I get this:

```
 Checking composer.json: OK

Checking platform settings: OK

Checking git settings: OK

Checking http connectivity to packagist: WARNING

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://packagist.org
/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: 
Connection timed out

Checking https connectivity to packagist: WARNING

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org
/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: 
Connection timed out

Checking github.com rate limit: OK

Checking disk free space: OK

Checking pubkeys: 

Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  
87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642

Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 
153E328C AD90147D AFE50952

OK

Checking composer version: 


 [Composer\Downloader
\TransportException]                                     

 The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: 
failed  

to open stream: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have a connectivity issue. Try resetting your internet connection and try again.

Comment: I tried, is not that. This is happening since yesterday

Comment: Acctually, I restarted my connection again and it worked. Is it a very weird behavior?

Comment: I don't think it is. Based on the diagnostic log you presented, it indicates a connectivity issue, Composer couldn't download the files it requires... I'd be happy to help if it happens again.